# Looping arraylist and display in datagridView , C# Winform

Tags: c#, arraylist, split, datagridview

I have some `productID` as **string** with comma let say `"10,11,12"` in variable `products` and I split them

```cs
string[] productlist = products.Split(',');
```

But when I want to display name of those products in **datagridview**, I only get the last one. Not all three products.

Here is my code:

```
foreach (var item in productlist)
{
                         
    int Pid = Convert.ToInt32(item);

    var pro = (from u in db.Product
               where u.ProductId == Pid
               select new
               {
                 Productname = u.ProductNamn
               }).Tolist();
            dgvProduct.DataSource = pro;

 }
```

How should my code look like? I know there is something wrong when I looping, but I don't know how to fix it.

I would very appreciate your help guys and thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are overwriting `dgvProduct.DataSource` on each iteration, which means the last iteration will be the only one that has an effect. You probably only want to set `dgvProduct.DataSource` outside the loop after collecting all the products. However, this can be done a little more effeciently:

```
// 'Select(int.Parse)' is short for 'Select(strId => int.Parse(strId))'
var prodIds = productlist.Select(int.Parse).ToList();

var products =
    (from u in db.Product
     where prodIds.Contains(u.ProductId)
     select new
     {
         Productname = u.ProductNamn
     }).Tolist();
dgvProduct.DataSource = products;
```

Comment: Well, it'll work perfectly until you try to edit them ;)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is:

If there are three items in productList, the foreach will run three times, one for each item.

When it finds a `product` in `db.Product` it calls

```cs
dgvProduct.DataSource = pro;
```

where `pro` is the `product` related to first item. But then the second item is found and again the line is called

```cs
dgvProduct.DataSource = pro;
```

but now for the second `product`. Finally the third item (last) is retrieven and

```cs
dgvProduct.DataSource = pro;
```

So at the end you are overriding `dgvProduct.DataSource = pro`, and of course the last one is the one that remains...

What i would do, although not sure if it works is make a collection with all the products and then set that collection to the `dgvProduct.DataSource`. Maybe something like

```cs
var pro = (from u in db.Product
    where productlist.Contains(u.ProductId.ToString())
    select new
    {
        Productname = u.ProductNamn
    }).Tolist();
dgvProduct.DataSource = pro;
```